# Query of queries not extracting data with data type mismatches

Tags: sql, coldfusion, qoq

My client has two databases, one for the latlng of places and another database for every other table (why I don't know). I'm working off of coldfusion and from what I can tell I need to do a query of queries since CF doesn't allow for multiple datasources in the same cfquery tag. Now for some reason the primary key in the latlng table is a string and the other table is a double (again why I don't know). But in the query I have now I am testing I am not pulling any data. I'm still trying to understand how the QoQ works exactly but I think I have the general idea down. Thanks!

```
<cfquery name="get_restrauntinfo" datasource="#listings#" dbtype="odbc">
SELECT *
FROM listings_new
WHERE pub_code = 'GridR'
</cfquery>

<cfquery name="get_latlng" datasource="#latlng#" dbtype="odbc">
SELECT member_id, mlat, mlong
FROM maps
</cfquery> 

<cfquery name="join_rest" dbtype="query">
SELECT *
FROM get_latlng, get_restrauntInfo 
WHERE 'parseInt(get_restrauntInfo.cli_number)' = get_latlng.member_id
</cfquery>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would, and have seconded Charlie's answer, but to fix your existing code, you could try replacing

```
'parseInt(get_restrauntInfo.cli_number)'
```

with

```
CAST( get_restrauntInfo.cli_number AS INTEGER )
```

in your WHERE clause.

Comment: do You think the QoQ will be more efficient then my answer below Or are the essentially doing the same thing?

Comment: Yes it will, because in your answer you are making another complete database call for each iteration of the first query loop. With QoQ there are only 2 database calls. But if you persevere with Charlie's advice you will have just one query, which is the ideal solution.

Answer (score 2):

While CF doesn't allow multiple datasources within the came cfquery tag, you *should* still be able to join across databases.  See: http://www.google.com/search?q=join+across+databases

Assuming that'll work for you, it seems a lot simpler than 2 separate queries and a QoQ on top of that.

Comment: sadly I already tried that and Coldfusion didn't like me trying to work around their tag design.

Comment: As long as it's valid SQL between the query tags, ColdFusion shouldn't care.  Can you elaborate as to what didn't work?  What was the error message?

Answer (score 0):

So what I ended up doing was using CFLOOP while I'm making probably more queries then I have to it works! Here is the code:

```
<cfloop query="get_restrauntinfo">
    <cfquery name="get_latlng" datasource="#latlng#" dbtype="odbc">
        SELECT member_id, mlat, mlong
        FROM maps
        WHERE member_id = '#get_restrauntinfo.cli_number#'
    </cfquery>
    <cfset title = #get_restrauntinfo.publish_as#>
    var content = addContent(#get_restrauntinfo#);
    <cfoutput query="get_latlng">
        var #toScript(title, "title")#;
        addMarker(#get_latlng.mlat#,#get_latlng.mlong#, title, content, map);
    </cfoutput> 
</cfloop>
```